# Selecionar todos os clientes e verificar se é transportadora e fornecedor

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Quero fazer um select que selecione todos os clientes e ao lado crie duas colunas uma chamada transportadora e outra fornecedor e em cada uma delas marcar sim ou não.

Ex:

```
     Código Nome   Fornecedor   Transportadora
     01     João    Sim          Não
     02     Maria   Não          Sim
```

Tenho os selects:

-- tabela de transportadora:

```
     select TraCod TR from T0055 TR, T0158 A where A.CliCod = TR.TraCod
```

-- tabela de fornecedor

```
     select * from T0185 F, T0158 A WHERE A.CliCod = F.ForCod
```

-- tabela de cliente

```
     select CliNom, CliReG, Clicgc, CliCgc2, CliNascCon, CliCid, CliCodUnf, 
     CliEnd, CliNum, CliBai, CliComple, CliCep, CliEmail, CliFon, CliFonCel  
      FROM T0158
```

Comment: Tu pode fazer um `LEFT JOIN` com cada tabela e checar se o `id` da tabela a direita é `NULL`. Se for é porque não é transportador/fornecedor

Comment: tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Essa é a ideia.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vjKyzwygEgV2dMoEpijw4t/0

Comment: ok , mas como que dá para fazer no sql server?

Comment: Se não me engano o MSSQL Server é só usar `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ou invés de  `LEFT JOIN`.
O conceito é o mesmo em qualquer banco relacional.

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca As colunas que relacionam as tabelas estão corretas nos exemplos? Por exemplo, a coluna TraCod é uma chave estrangeira na tabela T0055, apontando para o respectivo cliente?

Answer (score 2):

Na descrição do problema consta que a ligação entre as tabelas de transportadoras e de clientes é através do par {TraCod, CliCod} e que a ligação entre as tabelas de fornecedores e de clientes é através do par {ForCod, CliCod}.

Considerando-se isto, eis uma sugestão:

```
-- código #1
SELECT C.CliCod, C.CliNom, 
       case when T.Forcod is not null then 'Sim' else 'Não' end as Fornecedor,
       case when F.Tracod is not null then 'Sim' else 'Não' end as Transportadora
  from T0158 as C
       left join T0185 as F on F.ForCod = C.CliCod
       left join T0055 as T on T.TraCod = C.CliCod;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Fornecedores
Select C.CliCod As [Código], C.CliNom As [Nome],'Não' As Fornecedor,'Não' As Transportadora
From T0158

Union All
--Fornecedores
Select F.ForCod As [Código], F.ForNom As [Nome],'Sim' As Fornecedor,'Não' As Transportadora
From T0185 As F

Union All
--Transportadora
Select Tr.TraCod As [Código], Tr.TraNom As [Nome],'Não' As Fornecedor,'Sim' As Transportadora
From T0055 As Tr
```